# Mac keeps asking for VPN authentication information

Tags: mac, mojave, vpn

After updating my MacBook Air (MacOS Mojave) a window keeps popping up with the following message:

[image]

When I click cancel the window pops up again directly. I'm using Cyber Ghost VPN but I can't connect because it says there isn't any connection. In my keychain I searched for the Cyberghost password and tried to use that one but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What if the app doesnt support password saving ?

Comment: What did you update? macOS, CyberGhost VPN, something else? And from what version to what other version. Also include the macOS version in your original question.